# Check status of a forked process?

Tags: bash, fork, ps, nohup

I'm running a process that will take, optimistically, several hours, and in the worst case, probably a couple of days.

I've tried a couple of times to run it and it just never seems to complete (I should add, I didn't write the program, it's just a big dataset). I know my syntax for the command is correct as I use it all the time for smaller data and it works properly (I'll spare you the details as it is obscure for SO and I don't think that relevant to the question).

Consequently, I'd like to leave the program unattended running as a fork with `&`.
Now, I'm not totally sure whether the process is just grinding to a halt or is running but taking much longer than expected.

Is there any way to check the progress of the process other than `ps` and `top` + `1` (to check CPU use).

My only other thought was to get the process to output a logfile and periodically check to see if the logfile has grown in size/content.

As a sidebar, is it necessary to also use `nohup` with a forked command?

Comment: What do you mean check the progress, how is the program supposed to know how far through it is? If it has any ouput you could check how much there is of that at a given time though.

Comment: read thru my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737398/sass-watch-process-is-locking-up-my-terminal-window/5738359#5738359 . It may give you some other ideas about running your program and monitoring its status. Still as `123` says we need to know more about what output is being produced. ALSO, per your comment below, you are running on OSx. Add a tag for that, as it affects the solutions that are available. Good luck.

Comment: Well for instance, I know some programs can be set up such that they generate progress bars, but in this particular instance, it's running through several large files, and there would be output each time it completes one. Are there any issues with opening and reading a file that a process might still be writing to? I can obviously check it's size via `ls` without 'disturbing' the file, but that doesn't tell me if it's thrown an error or something...

Comment: @shellter I am on OSx, but the server I'm running all the commands on is Ubuntu

Comment: use iTerm to connect to your ubuntu machine. Start screen, run a program in that window. Issue the screen detach command. Shut down your iTerm. Go home, start a new terminal connection (iTerm, putty, many ohters) and reattach to you the running `screen` process and hence monitor the still running program. Good luck.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `screen` for this purpose. see the [man](http://ss64.com/bash/screen.html) for more reference
Brief summary how to use:

`screen -S some_session_name` - starts a new screen session named `session_name`

`Ctrl` + `a` + `d` - detach session

`screen -r some_session_name` returns you to your session

Comment: Would this be equivalent to starting a second shell instance in iTerm?

Comment: Good idea, but please remind O.P. to start his program before detaching ;-) ! Good luck to all.

Comment: I never used iTerm, so I can't tel anything about this

Comment: With iTerm you have the option to split your current shell. If you then `ssh` in to the same server in 2 shells you get 2 differet `tty` numbers, and so I'm guessing 2 instances of the shell does that. Would screen do the same?

Comment: Each screen gets a different process and a distinct (pseudo) tty, yes.