# crontab behaviour difference for mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, macos, bash, cron

I did tried to search, but nothing comes up that really works for me.
So i would start this thread to see if anyone can help. I hope this is not a stupid question that i overlook something simple.

I have a mac mini, that running with a MySQL server.

There is some day end job, so i put them into a script, trigger by a crontab (Actually I also tried launched as this is mac OS X, but same behavior)

crontab looks like this

```
15 00 * * * /Users/fgs/Documents/database/process_db.sh > /Users/fgs/Documents/database/output.txt 2>&1
```

the script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

#some data patching task before everything start

#This sql takes 3 sec

/usr/local/bin/mysql dbname -u root "-ppassword" < /Users/fgs/Documents/database/loadrawdata.sql 

#This sql takes 90 sec

/usr/local/bin/mysql dbname -u root "-ppassword" < /Users/fgs/Documents/database/LongLongsql.sql

#This sql takes 1 sec

/usr/local/bin/mysql dbname -u root "-ppassword" < /Users/fgs/Documents/database/anothersql.sql
```

Behavior:

A. When i execute the shell script directly in terminal, all the 3 sql works

B. When i execute this with crontab, the 90 sec SQL doesn't work (it is an insert into with a very big join, so there is no output printed, i did also tried to > output file, adding 2>&1, also no output), but the SQL before and after it works as expected.

C. To simulate crontab behavior, I tried to use

```
env - /bin/sh
```

and then start the shell script manually.

It appears that, the 90 sec `longlongsql.sql` was running only 5 sec, and skipped to the next line. No error message was displayed

I am wondering if there is any kind of timeout for crontab? (I did searched but found nothing)

I did checked ulimit is unlimited (checked within `"env - /bin/sh"`, and also did tried to put into the script)

I believe it is not related to mysql command, since it works fine by running same scripts (I also did searched this topic, and nothing interesting)

Just wondering if anyone can shed some light on me, a direction or whatever will help.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: can mysql read the sql /Users/fgs/Documents/database/LongLongsql.sql ?

Comment: I believe it can, when i execute command in bash, it works fine after 90 sec

Comment: have you test to start the script line from commandline # /usr/local/bin/mysql dbname -u root "-ppassword" < /Users/fgs/Documents/database/LongLongsql.sql

Comment: mysql has also a internal scheduler (Event). There you can also start your querys

Comment: Weird. more logging/debug/trace info seems to be your only hope. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5738359/620097 for some ideas. Add `set -x` to your script and then capture to file see if anything new turns up. Good luck.

Comment: Note the shebang `#!/bin/bash` must be on the **first** line of the shell script. Note2: dont put '\' before '#' , it is nonsense. note3: your shell script must be executable, try `chmod 755 /Users/fgs/Documents/database/process_db.sh` on it.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for your information , thats for illustration only, 1. the /bin/bash is on the first line. 2. It is executable, and working fine when direct execution in command line, and issue with one of the long sql in the middle. ## edited the scripts to make it looks better ( i am not good and handling stakeoverflow tag causing the script looks like syntax error)

Comment: @BerndBuffen It is working fine with mysql internal scheduler, Thanks for letting me know about this. (It looks a bit scary, i am a *nix guy, but it works anyway) I am using this as a workaround solution.

Comment: verify the setting of - 
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'interactive_timeout';
- it is possible that cron use wait_timeout for batch jobs.

Comment: @BerndBuffen, just tried to put 
show variables like 'wait_timeout';show variables like 'interactive_timeout';
into a sql file, tested with command line and crontab. 

Both have the same output. 
Variable_name Value
wait_timeout 28800
Variable_name Value
interactive_timeout 28800

Comment: mhhh, enable the general log and look if the 90 sec sql is in or if it not reach the server

Comment: @BerndBuffen, just enabled general log. In short, yes, it reached the server. I can see the long sql from the log.

                  923 Connect   root@localhost on ibps-prod
                  923 Query     select @@version_comment limit 1
                  923 Query     insert into course_times (recorded_date, in_status, course_id, member_id).........I will skip the middle part as it is not related........ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE out_status='正常'
                  923 Quit
Then comes in the next SQL command
                  924 Connect   root@localhost on ibps-prod

Comment: Did you check your cron error mail? Any issues with cron jobs get mailed to the user who owns the cronjob or the system mail.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that cron will start an isolated shell where it may not be able to read the file.
I would recommend to put your mysql-stuff inside a script. If you are able to execute the script, cron should also be able to do so.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    /usr/local/bin/mysql dbname -u root "-ppassword" < /Users/fgs/Documents/database/LongLongsql.sq
```

Or:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    /usr/local/bin/mysql --user=root --password=xxxxxx -e "/Users/fgs/Documents/database/LongLongsql.sq"
```

Then call the script from crontab...