# understanding and knowing the status of nohup process

Tags: python, linux, nohup

My script runs for 30+ hours so I want to keep it running in backgroup on my linux server.

I run like this

```
nohup python seq2seq.py > output.log &
```

Though this process appears running in background

```
root      2208  379 41.6 13014392 6839556 pts/3 Sl  10:48 138:58 python seq2seq.py
```

I could not see its execution log in `output.log` file.

I print message in script which should appear in log file if it's running. But looking at no content in log file I doubt whether this file correctly running or not.

Any clue to understand the status of this process?

Comment: Run strace on the process or lsof to check if the file is actually open.

Comment: @RamanSailopal: can you please give example for python script to do strace and lsof

Comment: Run "strace -p 2208" or "lsof | grep output.log"

Comment: errors will be written to std-err, so it may help to use `..> /path/to/output.log 2>&1` . OR see my more detailed answer for a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5738359/620097 (you'll have to read the initial Q and interpolate your situation into the O.P.s but it could solve your problem). Good luck.